# How to get background color for notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to make a custom RemoteViews based notification. But I find that background color of notification doesn't look consistent across different OEM and across different android version.

Is it's possible to find out the background color of system notification so that I can also use the same color for my custom notification.

If there is some suggestion to handle this issue, please share the solutions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a custom RemoteViews based notification? That path usually only leads to pain.

Comment: Yes... I need to some some complex UI there

Comment: @ianhanniballake is it possible to see the theme property